# Emailing powershell output

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that uses `Write-Output` to display the result of a for each loop.
I need to email the output and previously did this with VB using `sendemail.exe` as below

```
cscript //nologo script.vbs 2>&1 | sendEmail.exe -t mail@blah.co.uk -u "subject blah" -f mail@blah.co.uk -s smtpserver1.mail.co.uk
```

I am unable to get this working with powershell as when I run my .ps1 script it writes the output to the current console and does not pipe it to the sendemail.exe application. Do I need a different cmdlet or is it simpler to write the email function into the script?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use sendmail.exe at all with PowerShell. In PowerShell 2.0 and higher, use [Send-MailMessage](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849925.aspx) within your script itself. Capture your "output" to a variable to pass in with the `-Body` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Why not using this native cmdlet, if you are in powershell v2 or v3 ?

[`send-mailmessage`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx)